# Limit of $\frac{n^{n/2}}{n!}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$ since they are both products of $n$ elements but $n^n$ has each term equal to $n$ while $n!$ has each term decreasing by $1$. My intuition is that this limit goes to $0$ but I am not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: Try taking the logarithm.

Comment: Stirling approx. $n!$ ~ $\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$ Looks like $\to 0$.

Comment: $$
e^n  = 1 + n +  \cdots \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} +  \cdots  \ge \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} \Longrightarrow \left( {\frac{e}{{\sqrt n }}} \right)^n  \ge \frac{{n^{n/2} }}{{n!}}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's apply the ratio test corresponding to the related numerical series:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{(n-1)/2}}{n^{n/2}}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)^{n/2}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]^{1/2}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}\\\\
& = \sqrt{e}\times 0\\\\
& = 0 < 1
\end{align*}

hence the general term converges to zero.

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 1):

If $n=2k$, then
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{n^{n/2}}{n!}&=\dfrac{(2k)^{k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=\dfrac{k\cdots k}{(2k)\cdots(k+1)}\cdot\dfrac{2^{k}}{k!}\\
&\leq\dfrac{2^{k}}{k!}\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
If $n=2k+1$, then
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{n^{n/2}}{n!}&=\dfrac{(2k+1)^{(2k+1)/2}}{(2k+1)(2k)^{k}}\cdot\dfrac{(2k)^{k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{(2k+1)^{1/2}}\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{2k}\right)^{k}\dfrac{(2k)^{k}}{(2k)!}\\
&\rightarrow 0\cdot e^{1/2}\cdot 0\\
&=0.
\end{align*}